# Swing JLabel: Provide gap between text and underline

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

How to provide a some pixels gap between text and underline without to use HTML nor custom painting (like [here](http://esus.com/creating-an-underlined-jlabel-without-using-html/)), but using font attributes. Here is my MRE:

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.font.TextAttribute;
import java.util.Collections;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class LabelTryout {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Here is a underlined text");
        label.setFont(underlineFont(label.getFont()));
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        JFrame frm = new JFrame("Underline");
        frm.add(label);
        frm.setSize(300, 200);
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frm.setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the underline font for the given base font.
     * 
     * @param aBaseFont base font to paint it as underline.
     * @return underline font.
     */
    public static Font underlineFont(Font aBaseFont) {
        // here I want to provide gap for the base font.
        return aBaseFont.deriveFont(Collections.singletonMap(TextAttribute.UNDERLINE,
                                                             TextAttribute.UNDERLINE_ON));
    }

}
```

If it's not possible, please explain it.

Comment: @camickr the problem is that it's layout depended: works only when the label gets the preffered size.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for help. Please make your comment as answer, so I can upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any property that you can use to configure that.

If you don't want to extend the label to do the custom painting then you could try to:

1. use a `CompoundBorder`. You could use an `EmptyBorder` and a `MatteBorder` to simulate the painting of the line
2. The above approach is dependent on the layout and the label being displayed at its preferred size. To force this you could wrap the label in a `JPanel` with a `FlowLayout` since this layout respects the preferred size.
3. Create your own custom `Border`. The painting logic of the `Border` would look at the preferred size and the actual size and draw the line accordingly.
4. Create a custom `Icon` that uses the above approach as well.

These could be ways of doing the custom painting without extending the JLabel.